# Creating a Database with WIX Installer

Tags: sql, wix

I have a WIX project where I want to `create a database` from a SQL script. My script works perfectly when using in `MS SQL Management Studio` to execute it, but not in the WIX.

```
  <Fragment>
    <Component Id="CreateDatabase" Guid="D5D895A4-931A-4E19-BB66-C34C7659933B" KeyPath="yes" Directory="TARGETDIR">
      <util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="[DBUSER]" Password="[DBPWD]"/>
      <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Server="localhost" Database="master" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" User="SQLUser">
        <sql:SqlScript Id="InstallDatabaseScript" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="InstallDatabase" />
      </sql:SqlDatabase>
    </Component>
  </Fragment>
```

The error message is something like the wix doesn't understand the `Database="master"`, but I actually want to execute this script on the `master` database Anyone who got a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Its only a guess, but given that your script can't possibly be creating the master database, since it will already exist, and you have specified CreateOnInstall/DropOnUninstall, it seems reasonable for WiX to complain - it can neither create nor drop the master database...

Comment: I do not create the Master database in my script. I only specify the keyword `USE master GO Create DATABASE MyDatabase` in the script, but this script I want to execute on the master database.

Comment: yes, but WiX knows nothing about MyDatabase, and you have specified CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" which presumably WiX will take to relate to the master database